# Vidalia is not working, but Tor browser works fine. Vidalia log in details

Tags: vidalia

```
Aug 04 18:28:26.065 [Notice] Tor v0.2.2.35 (git-b04388f9e7546a9f). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Windows 8  [workstation])
Aug 04 18:28:26.065 [Warning] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Aug 04 18:28:26.065 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.17-stable using method win32. Good.
Aug 04 18:28:26.065 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 04 18:28:26.065 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Aug 04 18:28:26.394 [Notice] OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
Aug 04 18:28:28.133 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:28:28.134 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:28:31.660 [Warning] Tried connecting to router at 193.23.244.244:443, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 but got B0E8B26991725D15AD3F3F8F48FE8462E00A9805.
Aug 04 18:28:35.328 [Warning] Tried connecting to router at 86.59.21.38:443, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D but got B0E8B26991725D15AD3F3F8F48FE8462E00A9805.
Aug 04 18:28:55.539 [Warning] Your application (using socks5 to port 80) is giving Tor only an IP address. Applications that do DNS resolves themselves may leak information. Consider using Socks4A (e.g. via privoxy or socat) instead. For more information, please see https://wiki.torproject.org/TheOnionRouter/TorFAQ#SOCKSAndDNS. [20 similar message(s) suppressed in last 5 seconds]
Aug 04 18:28:55.542 [Notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Aug 04 18:28:55.678 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:28:55.678 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:28:57.282 [Warning] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 504 ("Gateway Timeout"). Closing.
Aug 04 18:28:57.282 [Warning] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 212.112.245.170:443
Aug 04 18:28:59.701 [Warning] Tried connecting to router at 86.59.21.38:443, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D but got B0E8B26991725D15AD3F3F8F48FE8462E00A9805.
Aug 04 18:29:00.925 [Warning] Tried connecting to router at 194.109.206.212:443, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 but got B0E8B26991725D15AD3F3F8F48FE8462E00A9805.
Aug 04 18:29:16.688 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:29:16.688 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:29:17.354 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:29:17.354 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:29:17.639 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:29:17.639 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:29:18.402 [Warning] socks5: command 3 not recognized. Rejecting.
Aug 04 18:29:18.402 [Warning] Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Aug 04 18:29:18.429 [Warning] Your application (using socks4 to port 6882) is giving Tor only an IP address. Applications that do DNS resolves themselves may leak information. Consider using Socks4A (e.g. via privoxy or socat) instead. For more information, please see https://wiki.torproject.org/TheOnionRouter/TorFAQ#SOCKSAndDNS. [10 similar message(s) suppressed in last 5 seconds]
Aug 04 18:29:18.433 [Notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you tell us more about your system & configuration?

Comment: Even if someone root causes this, Tor v0.2.2.35 linked against OpenSSL 1.0.0g should not be used for anything, since it is not secure.